# Trying to avoid Governor limits in no of SOQL queries

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

i have 2 custom objects appointment_*c and TimeDrive*_c.

Appointment has fields

1. startdate__c
2. contact__c

TimeDrive__c has

1. Target_date__c
2. contact__c
3. CreatedDate

Here is what i need to do

I need to get all get all records with in a specific date range

```
select id, Target_date__c, Contact__c,  Name, CreatedDate
                    from TimeDrive__c  where Target_date__c >=:startdate  and 
                    Target_date__c <=:enddate
```

i need to loop through each record in this list and check if there are appointments for this contact which has startdate fall between targetdate and createddate

Here is the bit i have done till now

```
        timeDriverLst = [select id, Target_date__c, Contact__c,  Name, CreatedDate
                    from TimeDrive__c  where Target_date__c >=:startdate  and 
                    Target_date__c <=:enddate ];

    if(timeDriverLst.size() >0){
    for(integer i =0; i < timeDriverLst.size(); i++)
    {
        mapTime.put(timeDriverLst[i].id, timeDriverLst[i]);

       /* appLst = [Select Name, Contact__c from Appointment__c where (StartDate__c > = :timeDriverLst[i].CreatedDate 
                 and StartDateTime__c <=:timeDriverLst[i].Target_date__c) and Contact__c = :timeDriverLst[i].Contact__c ];   
           */      

    }
```

I know i shouldnt have a SOQL query within a for loop. How can i avoid this and achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An ugly, but possibly usable solution: You could get all the contact ids from the time driver list and also find the earliest created date. Then you could pull out all the appointments whose contact id is in the contact id list and whose date is between the earliest created date and the target date. Then you would need to do a double loop, checking each appointment against each time driver. (Ordering the appts by contact or by date as you retrieve them might help here).

Comment: I could also think of only this option... Thanks